# laravel, auto-fill form fields from URL parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to properly set URL parameters to auto fill form fields in laravel

The form works and properly submits data but I have a URL like `testsite.com/register?email=email@test.com&password=dK94*DFj`

and I'd like to auto fill the form with the email and password from the URL

the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.register') }}">
    <div class="reg-card reg-margin-bottom">
        <div class="reg-card-content">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required value="{{ $invitation->email }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">New Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" required name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg-card">
        <div class="reg-card-content">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can I set this so that, as long as the params exist in the URL, then they autofill and disable those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by using

`{{ request()->email }}` and `{{ request()->password }}`

However, passing password in the url is no a good idea though!

Comment: Very true! haha, I'm changing that out because it's actually just a registration code but it was once a password field

Comment: So when I dump $request on the page, it's null actually

Comment: if  you want to check, do `dd(request()>all())` in blade view.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a cleaner URL, uou can create a route for the URl register.

```
Route::get('/register/{email?}/{hash?}',function($email,$hash){
     return view("viewFile",['email'=>$email,'password'=>$hash]);

});
```

In your view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.register') }}">
    <div class="reg-card reg-margin-bottom">
        <div class="reg-card-content">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required value="{{ $email }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">New Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" required name="password" value="{{$password}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg-card">
        <div class="reg-card-content">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't recommend you to pass a password in the url, but if it is a hash to validate that the email is the correct one, is a good idea I do it when I want to verified that the info is not changed by the user. Also this will need to hash the email and compare the hash with the one on the url.